# Disable CDI for a webapp on GlassFish 3

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, cdi, jboss-weld

We have an old web application (WAR) which contains common internal libraries. Lately we started using CDI in another project which uses the same internal libraries and some of the internal libraries got a `META-INF/beans.xml`.

Unfortunately we get various classloading errors during deploy on GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

```
[#|2014-03-14T14:11:20.302+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : 
com/example/SomethingState
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/SomethingState
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:927)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1476)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethodInfo(Class.java:959)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1132)
        at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1277)
        at java.lang.Class.isMemberClass(Class.java:1267)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.isNonStaticInnerClass(Reflections.java:139)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:78)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:123)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:350)
        at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:179)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:575)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:461)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:220)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.SomethingState
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
        ... 35 more
|#]

[#|2014-03-14T14:11:20.317+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[AutoDeploy] Autodeploy failed : /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/myapp.war.|#]
```

`SomethingState` is not in the `war` file (nor in the included `jar` files). It is a superclass of another class which CDI tries to load during scanning the classpath but it is not used by the webapp (nor the child class), so before CDI it was not a problem at all. If I remove the `beans.xml` from the included `jar`s the webapp works fine. I would like to avoid changing the `war` as well as including the missing `jar`s into it if that's possible.

How can we disable CDI for that webapp?

I've tried to put a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` into the `war` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" bean-discovery-mode="none">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```

It didn't work, the webapp still can't be deployed.

Another idea was deploying from command line with the following propert but it also didn't work:

```
bin/asadmin deploy  --property implicitCdiEnabled=false ~/myapp.war
```

Comment: Can you add a stack trace to help figure out what is dying when you remove the beans.xml in the war? Also, what you have won't work in CDI 1.0, that's a beans.xml file for CDI 1.1. You'd need to look at Weld beans.xml extensions for CDI 1.0

Comment: @LightGuard: Question updated, thanks for the comment! (It might be a typo in your comment but the webapp works fine without `beans.xml` files, the problems comes when it contains the `beans.xml` files.) Could you show an example of Weld `beans.xml` extensions?

Comment: Looks like one of the classes is referencing that com.example.SampleState class, but it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This was worked for me, on xwiki

bin/asadmin deploy  --property implicitCdiEnabled=false ~/myapp.war

Thanks anyways